# google-closure-compiler in node container gives libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.32 not found

Tags: linux, docker, google-closure-compiler

This used to work just fine in my Ubuntu machine with docker:

```
docker run --rm -t node:18 bash -c "npm i -g google-closure-compiler && google-closure-compiler --version"
```

Also tried the `node:19` image. Both `node:18` and `node:19` give the same error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/google-closure-compiler/node_modules/google-closure-compiler-linux/compiler: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/node_modules/google-closure-compiler/node_modules/google-closure-compiler-linux/compiler)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/google-closure-compiler/node_modules/google-closure-compiler-linux/compiler: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/node_modules/google-closure-compiler/node_modules/google-closure-compiler-linux/compiler)
```

Similar error if I install with `yarn global add google-closure-compiler` as per the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler):

```
/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/google-closure-compiler-linux/compiler: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/google-closure-compiler-linux/compiler)
/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/google-closure-compiler-linux/compiler: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/google-closure-compiler-linux/compiler)
```

I'm wondering what has changed and what would be the simplest way to fix it. Although there are many questions with *glibc* errors, haven't found one that had a solution for this particular case.

###### GLIBC Info

This is what I get in the `node:19` based container:

```bash
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.31-13+deb11u5) stable release version 2.31.
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 10.2.1 20210110.
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC ABSOLUTE
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.debian.org/Bugs/>.
```

So I understand the error, but I don't know why or when the closure compiler started requiring a higher GLIBC version, and most importantly, which docker image should I use to easily solve this.

###### Nothing Happens With Alpine Image

As an alternative, I tried the node image based on Alpine, which ironically [has this warning](https://hub.docker.com/_/node):

> The main caveat to note is that it does use musl libc instead of glibc
> and friends, so software will often run into issues depending on the
> depth of their libc requirements/assumptions.

Well, actually the *libc* error is gone now, but `google-closure-compiler` doesn't seem to do anything, see below:

```bash
$ docker run --rm -ti node:19-alpine sh
/ # npm i -g google-closure-compiler

added 27 packages in 30s

/ # google-closure-compiler --version
/ # google-closure-compiler
/ # google-closure-compiler --help
/ #
```

It literally outputs nothing. Any insights appreciated. As I said, it *used* to just work.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up reverting to the previous version. This is what was available:

```bash
npm view google-closure-compiler versions | grep -v nightly | tail
  '20220502.0.0',
  '20220601.0.0',
  '20220719.0.0',
  '20220803.0.0',
  '20220905.0.0',
  '20221004.0.0',
  '20221102.0.0',
  '20221102.0.1',
  '20230103.0.0',
```

And installed and tested `20221102.0.1`:

```bash
docker run --rm -t node:19 bash -c \
    "npm i -g google-closure-compiler@20221102.0.1 \
    && google-closure-compiler --version"
```

Output:

```
added 27 packages in 7s

Closure Compiler (http://github.com/google/closure-compiler)
Version: v20221102
```

Solved for now. Better solutions are still welcome.